# How to store and initialize data in React router components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

relatively new to React,

```
<Router>
        <Route path='/' component={Landing} />
        <Route path='/Players' exact render={(props) => (<> 
            <PlayerPage/>
          </>
        )}/>
        <Route path='/Teams' exact render={(props) => (<> 
            <TeamPage/>
          </>
        )}/>      
        <Route path='/about' component={About} />
</Router>
```

I have this setup where a landing page will redirect to various components which act as other pages. Problem is that I have a loadJSON() method in each component (PlayerPage and TeamPage).

```
const PlayerPage = () => {

    let initPlayers = loadPlayerJSON(tempPlayers)

    const [players, setPlayers] = useState(
        initPlayers, []
      )
...
```

Switching between each page seems to reinitialize the component and call this loadPlayerJSON() method every single time, which is obviously a problem as the JSON file grows large.

I sort of assumed that the pages would remain rendered in the background and switching between pages natively opitimized somehow, is this a problem with my set-up of the routes? Or is this just how it is going to be and I need to manually optimize the renders so that data doesn't take forever to reload when navigating pages?

Comment: Sounds like a job for shared state or [context](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use a solution like context which allows you to share information to any component, by storing it in a central place and allowing access to any component that requests it. It prevents you to request the same data each team when different components in the app render.
You can find more details here https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: Context is for smaller applications right ? For complex or big applications we can go with redux or redux-toolkit..

Comment: Yes . Context gets a little complex for bigger applications.